# Não quero que o scanner inicie antes do loop

Tags: java, loop, for, scanner

Estou tentando fazer um exercício em que tenho de ler 10 número com scanner e decidir qual o maior e o menor. Consegui fazer isso com um for loop pedindo 10 valores, porém, ao iniciar o scanner ele pede um valor a mais, antes de entrar no loop, queria que o programa pedisse input apenas ao chegar no loop. Esse é o código que eu consegui fazer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int max = n;
        int min = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            n = scan.nextInt();
            if  (n > max)
                max = n;
            if (n < min)
                min = n;
        }

        System.out.println("O maior número é: " + max);
        System.out.println("O menor número é: " + min);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: É por causa da linha `int n = scan.nextInt();`. Você não precisa iniciar uma leitura de scanner se não quer obter o dado de entrada do usuario. A simples inicialização da classe `Scanner` já e suficiente.

Comment: já tentei isso, porém, ao fazer isso a variável n fica com o erro "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Você não precisa iniciar a leitura do scanner, somente iniciar a variavel. Apenas um `int n = 0;` ja resolveria

Comment: Na verdade vc inicia o `min` com `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (o maior valor possível para um `int`), assim vc garante que qualquer número lido na primeira iteração será menor. O mesmo vale para `max`, basta iniciá-lo com `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: foi assim que consertei, se iniciar com int n = 0, o min nunca vai mudar

Answer (score -5):

seu codigo deveria esta parecido com esse.

```
 int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    int in = 0;
    int out = 0;

 for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        if (x >= 10 && x <= 20) {
            in = in + 1;
        }
        else {
            out = out + 1;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(in + " in");
    System.out.println(out + " out");
```

Comment: Continua errado, pois o problema está justamente em iniciar a variavel n com leitura do Scanner.